# 32 bit hex to 32 bit floating point (IEEE 754) conversion in matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, hex, ieee-754

How can I change the 32 bit hex-value to a floating point value according to the IEEE 754?

EDIT:

```
...
data = fread(fid,1,'float32');
disp(data);
...
```

I get this answer:

4.2950e+009
1.6274e+009
...

But how do I get 32 bit floating point (IEEE 754) numbers?

Comment: Why are you using `num2str`? Why aren't you just reading the value directly into a float with `fread`?

Comment: He told me that I have to use string-format. :/

Comment: num2str() returns a string in scientific format (e.g. 2.22e-16)... Not a hexadecimal value. So casting the output of num2str() to hex2num() is bound to fail...

Comment: I have hex-value in the file. And I need IEEE 754-single precicion value.

Answer (score 3):

Based on one of your comments it appears that your hexadecimal values are stored as strings of characters in a file. You first want to read these characters from the file in groups of 8. Depending on the specific format of your file (e.g. each set of 8 characters is on its own line, or they're separated by commas, etc.), you could use functions like [FSCANF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html) or [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) to do this. For example, if your data file looks like this:

```
409BFFFF
3B3C0000
85E60000
```

Then you can read the data into a character array like so:

```
fid = fopen(fileName,'r');  %# Open the file
data = textscan(fid,'%s');  %# Read the data
charArray = char(data{1});  %# Create a character array
fclose(fid);                %# Close the file
```

Now you need to convert these 32-bit hexadecimal strings to single-precision representations. The easiest way by far is to use the function [HEX2DEC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hex2dec.html) to convert the strings to integers (stored as double-precision values), convert them to unsigned 32-bit integers using the function [UINT32](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uint8.html), then cast the 32-bit integers to single-precision representations using the function [TYPECAST](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/typecast.html). Applying this to the sample data I have above gives these results:

```
>> values = typecast(uint32(hex2dec(charArray)),'single');
>> fprintf('% 1.42f\n',values);  %# Display the values
 4.874999523162841800000000000000000000000000
 0.002868652343750000000000000000000000000000
-0.000000000000000000000000000000000021629096
```

You can confirm that these results are correct using [this online hexadecimal-to-floating-point converter](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html).

---

In case anyone is interested, you *can* do the above type conversion yourself using the function [HEX2DEC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hex2dec.html) to first convert the string to an integer representation, then the function [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) to extract and process the bits for the [sign, exponent, and fraction of the single-precision number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format). For example:

```
>> a = '409BFFFF';  %# A sample hexadecimal value
>> b = hex2dec(a);  %# Convert to an integer
>> sign = bitget(b,32);                               %# Compute the sign
>> exponent = bitget(b,24:31)*2.^(0:7).';            %'# Compute the exponent
>> fraction = bitget(b,1:23)*2.^(-23:-1).';          %'# Compute the fraction
>> value = (-1)^sign*(1+fraction)*2^(exponent-127);   %# Compute the value
>> fprintf('%1.7f\n',value)                           %# Display the value
4.8749995
```