# Which endianness do I have?

Tags: endianness

In the manual they write FF8055AAh.
In the program I find the value AA5580FF. 
This isn't little or big-endian. But what is it?

Comment: Why are you sayings it not little or big endian.

Comment: One of them is (almost certainly) little-endian, and in that case the other is big-endian, but without more context it's impossible to say which is which. What value are they supposed to represent?

Comment: why is that not little-endian? assuming the first value is the original value...

Comment: it's simply wrong in the manual... Things like that happen all the time.

Comment: @Zimbabao I would expect the value AA5508FF and not AA5580FF.

Comment: there are many mistakes in the manual ... :/

Comment: Is there an other endian-system?

Comment: 80 is one byte .. it wont be 08. it will be 08 .. "ff 80 55 aa" reverse to "aa 55 80 ff".

Comment: @kame: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: There is something called "middle endian" .. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is little-endian (assuming that the value in the manual is big-engian). The bytes are { FF, 80, 55, AA } so when you reverse them you have { AA, 55, 80, FF }.

Comment: How can you be so sure that it's not big-endian, with bytes `{AA,55,80,FF}` instead?

Comment: Because I automatically assumed that the value in the manual is big-endian :)

Answer (score 1):

It is either little- or big-endian, if your processor is byte-oriented (which most modern processors are). Note that a byte is two hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your endianness using a small program as per the following:

http://c-faq.com/misc/endiantest.html

From what you posted your endianness is the opposite to the manuals.  The byte order swapping is confusing, but each word is stored in big or little endian which causes the swapping to be

From AABB CCDD to DDCC BBAA (16 bit words).

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232726/32-bit-hex-to-32-bit-floating-point-ieee-754-conversion-in-matlab) that you are wanting to convert these hexadecimal values to single-precision representations. Using an [online hexadecimal-to-floating-point converter](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html), this is what I get:

- `FF8055AA` becomes `-NaN`
- `AA5580FF` becomes `-1.8962955e-13`

So, the real question is, which one of these numbers looks like what you'd expect to see in your data file? Whichever one of these looks like what you want, treat the data file as having an endianness such that it gives you that value as a result when you load and convert it.

Comment: This value was not IEEE 754. There are many data type in this file.