# Convert Hex to single precision

Tags: matlab, floating-point, hex, precision, ieee-754

I'm struggling with converting a 32-bit hex expression into a single precision number in Matlab.

The `num2hex` function works fine for both. For example,

```
>> b = 0.4

b =

   0.400000000000000

>> class(b)

ans =

double

>> num2hex(b)

ans =

3fd999999999999a

>> num2hex(single(b))

ans =

3ecccccd
```

However, this does not work the other way around. The `hex2num` function *only* converts hexadecimal expression into doubles. So,

```
>> b = 0.4

b =

   0.400000000000000

>> num2hex(single(b))

ans =

3ecccccd

>> hex2num(ans)

ans =

    3.433227902860381e-006
```

Matlab simply pads zeros to make it a 64-bit hex. Is there a way to perform this conversion?

Comment: for the forward conversion (NUM2HEX), you can also use FPRINTF/SPRINTF: `sprintf('%bx',b)` and `sprintf('%tx',single(b))`

Comment: similar question: [32 bit hex to 32 bit floating point (IEEE 754) conversion in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232726/32-bit-hex-to-32-bit-floating-point-ieee-754-conversion-in-matlab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible with the built-in `hex2num`, but fortunately you can get a single precision version of `hex2num` (`hexsingle2num`) here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6927-hexsingle2num

Answer (score 10):

There's a way I found to do this usign built in functions in MATLAB

```
%#Let's convert 0x40100000 to Single Precision Float (should equal 2.25)

tempHex = '40100000';

tempVal = uint32(hex2dec(tempHex));

tempFloat = typecast(tempVal,'single')
%#result is 2.25
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it provides the exact desired functionality

Comment: if `hex2num` were not available,  `typecast(uint64(hex2dec('400921fb54442d18')),'double')`  works