# Matlab function/script to convert a real number to a hexidecimal single precision repersentation and back again

Tags: matlab, filter, floating-point, hex, vhdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32 bit hex to 32 bit floating point (IEEE 754) conversion in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232726/32-bit-hex-to-32-bit-floating-point-ieee-754-conversion-in-matlab)

I am trying to test the functionality of a filter written in VHDL, the input of this filter is a single precision floating point number. To do this I want to convert an array of real numbers in MATLAB, representing a sine wave to an array of hexadecimal representation of floating point numbers. Apply this array to the filter and convert the output to real values.

I.e. I need a function to perform the following `-3.48 = 0x"C05EB851"`, the function performed on [this site](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html) and it's inverse.

Does anyone have a MATLAB function/m-file to perform this operation? any help is greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: another similar question: [Convert Hex to single precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207413/convert-hex-to-single-precision)

Comment: Both those similar questions seem to be termed the other way around (hex->float).  Although the answer to this question is stated in the question part of one of those question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> help num2hex
 NUM2HEX Convert singles and doubles to IEEE hexadecimal strings.
    If X is a single or double precision array with n elements,
    NUM2HEX(X) is an n-by-8 or n-by-16 char array of the hexadecimal
    floating point representation.  The same representation is printed
    with FORMAT HEX.
```

Let's try your example:

```
>> num2hex(single(-3.48))

ans =

c05eb852
```

close enough?

Comment: Ya perfect should do the job thanks, and for the inverse I will use typecast(uint32(hex2dec('c05eb852')),'single');